# Date comparison on Kayako Query Language - KQL

Tags: querying

I am using Kayako Querying Language and trying to get the query to return all closed/resolved, closed/unresolved, and review tickets from a specified month. When I run the query, every ticket ever comes up, and it seems to ignore the date function I am using. What am I doing wrong?

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM ‘Tickets'
WHERE ‘Tickets.Creation Date’ = month(June 2016) AND ‘Tickets.Status’ = ‘Closed’ OR ‘Tickets.Status’ = ‘Resolved’ OR ‘Tickets.Status’ = ‘Unresolved'
GROUP BY ‘Tickets.Status'`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the date comparison in your `WHERE` clause for this:

`WHERE 'Tickets.Creation Date':Month = 6 and  'Tickets.Creation Date':Year = 2016`

Be also careful with the quotes, you sometimes use `‘` and others `'`